# Errors in numerical integration with different parameters

Tags: numerical-integration

Under different parameter systems, the results calculated by `NIntegrate` vary greatly, and I have failed to solve the problem by transforming `Method` and `MaxRecursion` and other schemes.

```
a = 0.0632206;
b = 13.18;
a0 = b/a;
EE = -0.000020218795869238787`;
R0 = 80*a0;
\[Beta]0 = Sqrt[-a/(2 b^2 EE)];
Rnl[r_] := 
  Hypergeometric1F1[3 - \[Beta]0, 
    6, (2 a r)/(\[Beta]0 b)] Exp[(-2 a r)/(2 \[Beta]0 b)] ((2 a r)/(\
\[Beta]0 b))^2;
Rnlh[p_?NumericQ] := 
  Sqrt[2/Pi]*
   NIntegrate[
    r^2 Rnl[r] (-((3 p r Cos[p r] + (-3 + (p r)^2) Sin[
             p r])/(p r)^3)), {r, 0, R0}];
B = Norm@Sqrt[1/NIntegrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]];
CC = NIntegrate[((5 (3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 
            1)^2)/(16 Pi))^3 Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}];
RR[\[Beta]_?NumericQ] := -1/2 Log[
    2 Pi B^(2 \[Beta]) CC NIntegrate[
      Abs[Rnlh[p]]^(2 \[Beta]) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]];
RR[3]
```

> -499.6682507838183861

This result is incorrect, and the result under another set of parameters is given below.
When I switch to another set of parameters, I can get the correct result.

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
a0 = b/a;
EE = -0.05555555555555555`;
R0 = 80*a0;
\[Beta]0 = Sqrt[-a/(2 b^2 EE)];
Rnl[r_] := 
  Hypergeometric1F1[3 - \[Beta]0, 
    6, (2 a r)/(\[Beta]0 b)] Exp[(-2 a r)/(2 \[Beta]0 b)] ((2 a r)/(\
\[Beta]0 b))^2;
Rnlh[p_?NumericQ] := 
  Sqrt[2/Pi]*
   NIntegrate[
    r^2 Rnl[r] (-((3 p r Cos[p r] + (-3 + (p r)^2) Sin[
             p r])/(p r)^3)), {r, 0, R0}];
B = Norm@Sqrt[1/NIntegrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]];
CC = NIntegrate[((5 (3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 
            1)^2)/(16 Pi))^3 Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}];
RR[\[Beta]_?NumericQ] := -1/2 Log[
    2 Pi B^(2 \[Beta]) CC NIntegrate[
      Abs[Rnlh[p]]^(2 \[Beta]) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]];
RR[3]
```

> -2.31128

Appendix:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 0.0632206 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
b = 13.18 // Rationalize;
a0 = b/a;
EE = -0.000020218715097548605` // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
R0 = 40*a0;
\[Beta]0 = Sqrt[-a/(2 b^2 EE)];

Rnl[r_] = 
  Hypergeometric1F1[3 - \[Beta]0, 
    6, (2 a r)/(\[Beta]0 b)] Exp[(-2 a r)/(2 \[Beta]0 b)] ((2 a r)/(\
\[Beta]0 b))^2;

Rnlh[p_] = 
  Sqrt[2/Pi] Integrate[
    r^2 Rnl[r] (-((3 p r Cos[p r] + (-3 + (p r)^2) Sin[
             p r])/(p r)^3)), {r, 0, R0}];

B = Norm@Sqrt[1/Integrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]];

CC = Integrate[((5 (3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 
            1)^2)/(16 Pi))^3 Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}];

RR[\[Beta]v_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{\[Beta] = SetPrecision[\[Beta]v, 20]}, -1/2 Log[
     2 Pi B^(2 \[Beta]) CC NIntegrate[
       Abs[Rnlh[p]]^(2 \[Beta]) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 15]]];
sol = RR[3]
```

Comment: Code does not evaluate. What is the value of `l` (lower case L)?

Comment: Sorry for the oversight, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Most of the integrals can be done exactly rather than having to be done numerically.

```
a = 0.0632206 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
b = 13.18 // Rationalize;
a0 = b/a;
EE = -0.000020218795869238787` // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
R0 = 80*a0;
β0 = Sqrt[-a/(2 b^2 EE)];

Rnl[r_] = 
  Hypergeometric1F1[3 - β0, 
    6, (2 a r)/(β0 b)] Exp[(-2 a r)/(2 β0 b)] ((2 a r)/(β0 \
b))^2;

Rnlh[p_] = 
  Sqrt[2/Pi] Integrate[
    r^2 Rnl[r] (-((3 p r Cos[p r] + (-3 + (p r)^2) Sin[p r])/(p r)^3)), {r, 0,
      R0}];

B = Norm@Sqrt[1/Integrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]];

CC = Integrate[((5 (3 Cos[θ]^2 - 
            1)^2)/(16 Pi))^3 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}];

RR[βv_?NumericQ] := Module[{β = SetPrecision[βv, 20]},
   -1/2 Log[
     2 Pi B^(2 β) CC NIntegrate[
       Abs[Rnlh[p]]^(2 β) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity},
       WorkingPrecision -> 15]]];
```

It is not clear what value you are expecting here.

```
sol = RR[3]

(* -18.330760442758718 *)
```

For the second set of parameters:

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
a0 = b/a;
EE = -0.05555555555555555` // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
R0 = 80*a0;
β0 = Sqrt[-a/(2 b^2 EE)];

Rnl[r_] = 
  Hypergeometric1F1[3 - β0, 
    6, (2 a r)/(β0 b)] Exp[(-2 a r)/(2 β0 b)] ((2 a r)/(β0 \
b))^2;

Rnlh[p_] = 
  Sqrt[2/Pi] Integrate[
    r^2 Rnl[r] (-((3 p r Cos[p r] + (-3 + (p r)^2) Sin[p r])/(p r)^3)), {r, 0,
      R0}];

B = Norm@Sqrt[1/Integrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]];

CC = Integrate[((5 (3 Cos[θ]^2 - 
            1)^2)/(16 Pi))^3 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}];

RR[βv_?NumericQ] := Module[{β = SetPrecision[βv, 20]},
   -1/2 Log[
     2 Pi B^(2 β) CC NIntegrate[
       Abs[Rnlh[p]]^(2 β) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity},
       WorkingPrecision -> 15]]];

sol = RR[3]

(* -2.311283609290016 *)
```

**EDIT:** Although the initial values that you provided resulted in the `Hypergeometric1F1` simplifying and enabled exact evaluation of most of the integrals, the parameters provided later do not and require more numeric integration. Restructuring the solution as a function:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

CC = Integrate[((5 (3 Cos[θ]^2 - 
            1)^2)/(16 Pi))^3 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}];

RR[av_?NumericQ, bv_?NumericQ, EEv_?NumericQ, 
  R0fv_?NumericQ, βv_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{
   a = Rationalize[av, 0],
   b = Rationalize[bv, 0],
   EE = Rationalize[EEv, 0],
   R0f = Rationalize[R0fv, 0],
   β = Rationalize[βv, 0]},
  a0 = b/a;
  β0 = Sqrt[-a/(2 b^2 EE)];
  R0 = R0f*a0;
  Rnl[r_] = 
   Hypergeometric1F1[3 - β0, 6, (2 a r)/(β0 b)] *
    Exp[(-2 a r)/(2 β0 b)] *((2 a r)/(β0 b))^2;
  Rnlh[pv_?NumericQ] := Module[{p = Rationalize[pv, 0]},
    Sqrt[2/Pi] NIntegrate[
      r^2 Rnl[r] (-((3 p r Cos[p r] + (-3 + (p r)^2) 
       Sin[p r])/(p r)^3)), 
      {r, 0, R0},
      WorkingPrecision -> 15]];
  B = Norm@Sqrt[1/NIntegrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity},
       WorkingPrecision -> 15]];
  -1/2 Log[
    2 Pi B^(2 β) CC NIntegrate[
      Abs[Rnlh[p]]^(2 β) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 15]]]
```

For the given examples,

```
AbsoluteTiming[RR[0.0632206, 13.18, -0.000020218795869238787`, 80, 3]]

(* {7.50461, -18.33076044332826} *)

AbsoluteTiming[RR[1, 1, -0.05555555555555555`, 80, 3]]

(* {1.27829, -2.31128360933903} *)
```

The following is extremely slow

```
AbsoluteTiming[RR[0.0632206, 13.18, -0.000020218715097548605`, 40, 3]]

(* {419.52, -18.33201635845343} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. But I can't get the result successfully when I test another set of data (for example, when `EE = -0.00001964086503595607 // Rationalize[#, 0] &`; `R0 = 20*a0`; or `EE = -0.000020218715097548605 // Rationalize[#, 0] &`; `R0 = 40*a0`; I added it to my question.), why is that? @Bob Hanlon